# How to add ItemTemplate to a gridview programatically

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview

I am trying add multiple images to a column in a data grid view in ASP.net using C#

the image names are in the database and some Users will have 10 images and others will have no images and some will be somewhere inbetween.

I figured out I can add an ItemTemplate but what I want is on load to generate the number programmatically,

is this possible

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dgvTopPlayers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onrowdatabound="dgvTopPlayers_RowDataBound" 
        onrowcreated="dgvTopPlayers_RowCreated" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="UserID" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/UserProfile.aspx?UserId={0}" 
                DataTextField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
                />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last7Days" HeaderText="Last7Days" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastMonth" HeaderText="LastMonth" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPoints" HeaderText="TotalPoints" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IdeaCount" HeaderText="IdeaCount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChallengeCount" HeaderText="ChallengeCount" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badges"  >
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
                        Tooltip='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' />
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" AlternateText='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
                        ImageUrl="~/Images/puzzleIcon.png" />
                        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" AlternateText='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
                        ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/caution.png" />
                        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" AlternateText='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
                        ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/reportabuse.png" />
                        <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" AlternateText='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
                        ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/yellow_star.png" />
                </ItemTemplate>


                <ItemStyle Width="35%" />


            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place a panel or placeholder inside `ItemTemplate`, and add images inside RowDataBound since you already have it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badges"  >
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>' 
         Tooltip='<%# Eval("BadgeIcons") %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="ImagePanel".../>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


void dgvTopPlayers_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      // *** Cast to appropiate object ***
      var user = e.Row.DataItem as User;
      var panel = e.Row.FindControl("ImagePanel") as Panel;
      var images = user.BadgeIcons.Split(',');      
      foreach(var img in images) {
         panel.Controls.Add(new Image{ ID = UniqueID, ImageUrl = "~/IMAGES/" + img });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, 1 last problem all the strings are in BADGEICONS,  so they are a string "img1.png,img2.png,img2.png,...   Bow do I reaccess Badgeicons in the code behind, badgeicons is part of a list

Comment: I updated the answer. Please make sure you cast  `e.Row.DataItem` to appropiate object. For example, `DataRowView` if data source is `DataView` or `DataTable`.